# How do I import @orange-games/phaser-ads node module?

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have installed [Phaser Ads](https://github.com/orange-games/phaser-ads) using `npm install @orange-games/phaser-ads`.

```
node_modules/@orange-games
└── phaser-ads
    ├── CODE_OF_CONDUCT.md
    ├── CONTRIBUTING.md
    ├── LICENSE
    ├── README.md
    ├── build
    │   ├── phaser-ads.d.ts
    │   ├── phaser-ads.js
    │   ├── phaser-ads.js.map
    │   └── phaser-ads.min.js
    ├── package.json
    ├── tsconfig.json
    ├── tslint.json
    └── vendor
        ├── cocoon.d.ts
        ├── cordova-gamedistribution.d.ts
        ├── cordova-heyzap.d.ts
        ├── game-distribution.d.ts
        └── google-ima3-sdk.d.ts
```

When I import another module, say Lodash, I use

```
import _ from 'lodash'
```

However, I get an error when importing PhaserAds:

```
import PhaserAds from '@orange-games/phaser-ads';

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@orange-games/phaser-ads' in '/Users/frank/Stuff/inferno/src/states'
```

It appears, that the app is trying to import it from the local folder but I do not why this isn't the case with Lodash. Is it because Lodash is already required by something else and is already in the bundle?

Do I need to add anything to my webpack config?

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {

  /**
   * Minimal build setup.
   * Create your app bundle.
   */

  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'assets', 'scripts')
  },

  /**
   * Minimal development setup.
   * Serves files in ./public folder.
   * Refresh browser automatically when your bundle changes.
   */

  devServer: {
    publicPath: '/assets/scripts/',
    contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
    port: 3000
  },

  module: {
    rules: [
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
      use: {
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        options: {
          presets: ['env']
        }
      }
    }]
  }
};
```

Comment: Have you tried importing from the build folder from phaser-ads?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the key `main` is missing in `package.json` of `phaser-ads`, so webpack don't know which script to load when you import the package.

I don't think that we can import the package like that, in the official doc they import it using the `<script>` tag.

Maybe you should report an issue to the package team, or make a PR :p